# Numeric sorting is not working in uitable of Matlab. Need assisstance to override some JIDE methods in matlab

Tags: matlab, uitableview, sorting, jide

I am trying to sort a matlab ui table columns(created using jide). But instead of getting sorted numerically, it is getting sorted based on string. Ex if i have 4,44,2,22,1,11 it gets sorted like 1,11,2,22,4,44 instead of 1,2,4,11,22,44

```
            Scroll=lib.findjobj(m.thandle);
            m.hjtable = Scroll.getViewport.getView;
            m.hjtable.setNonContiguousCellSelection(false);
            m.hjtable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
            m.hjtable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);




            % Make table sortable on columns
            m.hjtable.setSortable(true);
            m.hjtable.setAutoResort(true);
            m.hjtable.setMultiColumnSortable(true);
            m.hjtable.setPreserveSelectionsAfterSorting(true);
```

Comment: I want to sort the numbers this way (e.g. 145 129 90 2 -1) inside my uitable htable. Instead the following code sorts the numbers in that way (-1 129 145 2 90). It´s obvious that the program is just sorting after the first numeric value. Has someone got a clue about how to sort these numbers right? Below you will find the current code, which implements the sorting (Credits to Yair Altman).
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: % Display the uitable and get its underlying Java object handle
jscrollpane = findjobj(hTable);
jtable = jscrollpane.getViewport.getView;
 % Now turn the JIDE sorting on
jtable.setSortable(true);    
jtable.setAutoResort(true);
jtable.setMultiColumnSortable(true);
jtable.setPreserveSelectionsAfterSorting(true);

Comment: Please add updates to the question itself using [edit]. Comments are the wrong place for clarifications and code.